# Could not load Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, crash, gnu

I am updating my with `sudo apt-get upgrade` and in the middle of updating my laptop power goes down.when I start it again it show the gnu grub and didn't load ubuntu I tried `exit` command and it goes to boot options.what should I do?!
How can I recover Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried starting the computer with a Live USB and reinstalling Grub??

Comment: No. I am looking for an alternative and afraid losing my data if that goes wrong